# Bounding box on objects based on color python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I try to draw a  bounding box on every object in this picture, i wrote this code from [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

```
import cv2 as cv2
import os
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('1 (2).png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
for item in range(len(contours)):
    cnt = contours[item]
    if len(cnt)>20:
        print(len(cnt))
        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.imshow('image',img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the result is only one object,
 [image: pic1]

when i change the value 127 in this line to 200 in this line `ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)` i got different object.
[image: pic2]

here's the original image
 [image: original picture]

The question is how can i detect all objects once?

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: The question how can i detect all objects once? @api55

Comment: first step is to read the manual: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours

Comment: Since you are interested in colour (or hue to be specific), it seems rather counterproductive to discard all the colour information by converting the BGR image to grayscale. Perhaps using the hue component from HSV or HSL would work better?

Comment: @ZeyadEtman I'll give you the +1, but please [edit] your question, and add the necessary `import` statements to your sample script, so that someone else can simply copy and paste it and then run it without needs to make any significant modifications (other than, say, changing the filename). Otherwise well done on providing the necessary information. :)

Comment: @ZeyadEtman Great. Just reading through the code, I noticed the following -- in the calls to `cv2.threshold`  and `cv2.findContours` you use "magic numbers" for some of the parameters. In first case the `0` should be `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` and in second, the `1` a `cv2.RETR_LIST` and the `2` a `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`. It's always better to use the named constants for those parameters -- I hope you see how that makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: @ZeyadEtman Does [this](https://pastebin.com/HcEeH1tn) do something close to what you want? -- I just find the dominant hues, create masks of the areas that contains pixels of that hue, and then use the masks to create individual images. It disregards the transitions between the areas that are of slightly different hue. You could use the masks to determine bounding boxes.

Comment: it works! You made my day :) Please write it in answer to upvote it :) Thanks So much. @DanMašek

Comment: @ZeyadEtman Glad to help. I'll add some cropping of the detected "blobs" and will write up and answer. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The approach is fairly straightforward. We begin by converting to HSV and grabbing only the hue channel.

```
image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,_,_ = cv2.split(image_hsv)
```

Next, we find the dominant hues -- first count the occurrences of each hue using [`numpy.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) (we [`flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) the hue channel image to make it one-dimensional):

```
bins = np.bincount(h.flatten())
```

And then find which ones are common enough using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
MIN_PIXEL_CNT_PCT = (1.0/20.0)
peaks = np.where(bins > (h.size * MIN_PIXEL_CNT_PCT))[0]
```

Now that we've identified all the dominant hues, we can repeatedly process the image to find the areas correspond to each of them:

```
for i, peak in enumerate(peaks):
```

We begin by creating a mask which selects all the pixels of this hue ([`cv2.inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981), and then extracting the corresponding parts from the input BGR image ([`cv2.bitwise_and`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14).

```
mask = cv2.inRange(h, peak, peak)
blob = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
```

Next, we find the contours ([`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) of all the continuous areas of this hue, so that we can process each of them individually

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Now, for each of the identified continuous area

```
for j, contour in enumerate(contours):
```

We determine the bounding box ([`cv2.boundingRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gacb413ddce8e48ff3ca61ed7cf626a366), and create a mask corresponding to just this contour by filling the contour polygon with white ([`numpy.zeros_like`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html) and [`cv2.drawContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc))

```
bbox = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
contour_mask = np.zeros_like(mask)
cv2.drawContours(contour_mask, contours, j, 255, -1)
```

Then we can extra just the ROI corresponding to the bounding box

```
region = blob.copy()[bbox[1]:bbox[1]+bbox[3],bbox[0]:bbox[0]+bbox[2]]
region_mask = contour_mask[bbox[1]:bbox[1]+bbox[3],bbox[0]:bbox[0]+bbox[2]]
region_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(region, region, mask=region_mask)
```

Or visualize ([`cv2.rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9) the bounding box:

```
result = cv2.bitwise_and(blob, blob, mask=contour_mask)
top_left, bottom_right = (bbox[0], bbox[1]), (bbox[0]+bbox[2], bbox[1]+bbox[3])
cv2.rectangle(result, top_left, bottom_right, (255, 255, 255), 2)
```

Or do any other processing you want.

---

### Full Script

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Minimum percentage of pixels of same hue to consider dominant colour
MIN_PIXEL_CNT_PCT = (1.0/20.0)

image = cv2.imread('colourblobs.png')
if image is None:
    print("Failed to load iamge.")
    exit(-1)

image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# We're only interested in the hue
h,_,_ = cv2.split(image_hsv)
# Let's count the number of occurrences of each hue
bins = np.bincount(h.flatten())
# And then find the dominant hues
peaks = np.where(bins > (h.size * MIN_PIXEL_CNT_PCT))[0]

# Now let's find the shape matching each dominant hue
for i, peak in enumerate(peaks):
    # First we create a mask selecting all the pixels of this hue
    mask = cv2.inRange(h, peak, peak)
    # And use it to extract the corresponding part of the original colour image
    blob = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for j, contour in enumerate(contours):
        bbox = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        # Create a mask for this contour
        contour_mask = np.zeros_like(mask)
        cv2.drawContours(contour_mask, contours, j, 255, -1)

        print "Found hue %d in region %s." % (peak, bbox)
        # Extract and save the area of the contour
        region = blob.copy()[bbox[1]:bbox[1]+bbox[3],bbox[0]:bbox[0]+bbox[2]]
        region_mask = contour_mask[bbox[1]:bbox[1]+bbox[3],bbox[0]:bbox[0]+bbox[2]]
        region_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(region, region, mask=region_mask)
        file_name_section = "colourblobs-%d-hue_%03d-region_%d-section.png" % (i, peak, j)
        cv2.imwrite(file_name_section, region_masked)
        print " * wrote '%s'" % file_name_section

        # Extract the pixels belonging to this contour
        result = cv2.bitwise_and(blob, blob, mask=contour_mask)
        # And draw a bounding box
        top_left, bottom_right = (bbox[0], bbox[1]), (bbox[0]+bbox[2], bbox[1]+bbox[3])
        cv2.rectangle(result, top_left, bottom_right, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        file_name_bbox = "colourblobs-%d-hue_%03d-region_%d-bbox.png" % (i, peak, j)
        cv2.imwrite(file_name_bbox, result)
        print " * wrote '%s'" % file_name_bbox
```

### Console Output

```
Found hue 32 in region (186, 184, 189, 122).
 * wrote 'colourblobs-0-hue_032-region_0-section.png'
 * wrote 'colourblobs-0-hue_032-region_0-bbox.png'
Found hue 71 in region (300, 197, 1, 1).
 * wrote 'colourblobs-1-hue_071-region_0-section.png'
 * wrote 'colourblobs-1-hue_071-region_0-bbox.png'
Found hue 71 in region (301, 195, 1, 1).
 * wrote 'colourblobs-1-hue_071-region_1-section.png'
 * wrote 'colourblobs-1-hue_071-region_1-bbox.png'
Found hue 71 in region (319, 190, 1, 1).
 * wrote 'colourblobs-1-hue_071-region_2-section.png'
 * wrote 'colourblobs-1-hue_071-region_2-bbox.png'
Found hue 71 in region (323, 176, 52, 14).
 * wrote 'colourblobs-1-hue_071-region_3-section.png'
 * wrote 'colourblobs-1-hue_071-region_3-bbox.png'
Found hue 71 in region (45, 10, 330, 381).
 * wrote 'colourblobs-1-hue_071-region_4-section.png'
 * wrote 'colourblobs-1-hue_071-region_4-bbox.png'
Found hue 109 in region (0, 0, 375, 500).
 * wrote 'colourblobs-2-hue_109-region_0-section.png'
 * wrote 'colourblobs-2-hue_109-region_0-bbox.png'
Found hue 166 in region (1, 397, 252, 103).
 * wrote 'colourblobs-3-hue_166-region_0-section.png'
 * wrote 'colourblobs-3-hue_166-region_0-bbox.png'
```

### Example Output Images

Yellow bounding box:

[image: Hue 32 bounding box]

Yellow extracted region:

[image: Hue 32 section]

Biggest green bounding box (there are several other small disjoint areas as well):

[image: Hue 71 largest bounding box]

...and the corresponding extracted region:

[image: Hue 71 largest section]

Comment: How can I used this method for grayscale or single channel images?

Comment: I get "TypeError: lowerb is not a numpy array, neither a scalar" on line  mask = cv2.inRange(h, peak, peak)

Answer (score 1):

First step is to understand what your algorithm is doing...specifically this function:
`ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)`

the value `127` is the greyscale value between 0 and 255. Threshold function changes pixel values below 127 to 0 and above 127 to 255

With reference to your coloured image, the greyscale output for both the green blob and yellow blob is above 127, so both of those are changed to 255, and hence both are captured by the `findContours()` method

You can run `imshow` on `thresh` object to understand exactly what is going on.

Now when you replace `127` with `200`, only the yellow blob has a greyscale value above 200, so only that blob is seen in the `thresh` Mat

To detect "all objects" at once, please experiment further with `threshold` method and study the `thresh` object using `imshow`