# Find Cords of color mask in OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to get the cords of the colored area after applying the color mask.  I have tried the solution here [Find the coordinates in an image where a specified colour is detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60051941/find-the-coordinates-in-an-image-where-a-specified-colour-is-detected) but my array is blank and I believe it is because my color range is not accurate.

Here is the image I get after applying the mask and converting it from HSV to BRG.  My endstate is to track the movement of this object but first need to find the cords to track the change in X,Y.
[image: image I am using]

Here is my code for the mask.

```
def color_mask(image, debug_mode=True):
  min_hsv = (1,134,64)
  max_hsv = (179,212,255)
  hsv = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  img_mask = cv.inRange(hsv, min_hsv, max_hsv)
  result = cv.bitwise_and(hsv, hsv, mask=img_mask)
  img = cv.cvtColor(result, cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
  red_x, red_y = np.where(np.all(img==[0,0,255], axis=2)) # This color isnt right but idk how to find the right one
  print(red_y)

  if debug_mode:
      cv.imshow("mask", img_mask)
      cv.imshow("img", img)
  return img
```

Comment: this should help you -->> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051916/bounding-box-on-objects-based-on-color-python

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed thank you!